# How to make textformfield and dropdownmenu close?

Tags: flutter, dart

This is the design I want:
[image]

This is my current design:
[image]

How to make textfromfield and dropdownmenu close like in the design I showed. And another thing is how to make the circlebox have the same distance as in the design. I have tried but without success. Please guide. I am new to using flutter.

This is my code:

```
Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 150),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(height: 35),
                  Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 10, 20),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        width: 1.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              child: Wrap(
                                direction: Axis.horizontal,
                                alignment: WrapAlignment.end,
                                crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      border: Border.all(
                                        color: Colors.transparent,
                                        width: 1.0,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    child: Center(
                                      child: FutureBuilder(
                                        future: _getSignedURL(
                                            widget.patientProfile.avatar),
                                        builder: (BuildContext context,
                                            AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                                          if (snapshot.data == null) {
                                            return Container(
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                              child: Container(
                                                width: 200,
                                                height: 200,
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  color: Color.fromRGBO(
                                                      255, 255, 255, 0.3),
                                                  border: Border.all(
                                                    color: Colors.black12,
                                                    width: 1.0,
                                                  ),
                                                  borderRadius:
                                                      BorderRadius.all(
                                                          Radius.circular(
                                                              200.0)),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            );
                                          } else {
                                            return CircleAvatar(
                                              radius: 100,
                                              backgroundImage:
                                                  NetworkImage(snapshot.data),
                                            );
                                          }
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  new Positioned(
                                      left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                                          100,
                                      top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                          200,
                                      child: Container(
                                        width: 200,
                                        height: 50,
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          border: Border.all(
                                            color: Colors.transparent,
                                            width: 1.0,
                                          ),
                                        ),

                                        // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                                        child: OutlinedButton(
                                          style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                                            //primary: Colors.white,
                                            //backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                            side: BorderSide(
                                                color: Colors.blue, width: 1),
                                          ),
                                          child: Text(
                                            'Save Profile',
                                            style:
                                                TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                                          ),
                                          onPressed: () =>
                                              _updatePatientProfile(),
                                        ),
                                      )),
                                  Container(
                                    width: double.infinity,
                                    margin:
                                        const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0),
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                        horizontal: 100),
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      border: Border.all(
                                        color: Colors.transparent,
                                        width: 1.0,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    child: Row(
                                      children: [
                                        Expanded(
                                          child: Column(
                                            crossAxisAlignment:
                                                CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                            children: [
                                              SizedBox(
                                                height: 30,
                                                child: Text(
                                                  '* MRN',
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight.bold,
                                                      fontSize: 16),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              SizedBox(
                                                width: 300,
                                                child: TextFormField(
                                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                                      color: Colors.black),
                                                  controller: mrn,
                                                  onSaved: (String? value) {
                                                    mrn.text = value!;
                                                  },
                                                  decoration:
                                                      const InputDecoration(
                                                    border:
                                                        OutlineInputBorder(),
                                                    hintText: 'MRN',
                                                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                                        color: Colors.black,
                                                        fontSize: 16),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              )
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Expanded(
                                          child: Column(
                                            crossAxisAlignment:
                                                CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                            children: [
                                              SizedBox(
                                                height: 30,
                                                child: Text(
                                                  '* Salutation',
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight.bold,
                                                      fontSize: 16),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              SizedBox(
                                                width: 10,
                                              ),
                                              Container(
                                                  height: 55,
                                                  //width: 30,
                                                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                      horizontal: 10,
                                                      vertical: 5),
                                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                      border: Border.all(
                                                        color: Colors.black12,
                                                        width: 1.0,
                                                      ),
                                                      borderRadius:
                                                          BorderRadius.circular(
                                                              5)),
                                                  child: SizedBox(
                                                    width: 300,
                                                    child:
                                                        DropdownButton<String>(
                                                      underline: Container(
                                                          color: Colors
                                                              .transparent),
                                                      hint: _salutation == null
                                                          ? Text(
                                                              '* Salutation',
                                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                                  color: Colors
                                                                      .red),
                                                            )
                                                          : Text(_salutation),
                                                      isExpanded: true,
                                                      value: _salutation,
                                                      items: <String>[
                                                        'Mr.',
                                                        'Mrs.',
                                                        'Ms.'
                                                      ].map((String value) {
                                                        return new DropdownMenuItem<
                                                            String>(
                                                          value: value,
                                                          child:
                                                              new Text(value),
                                                        );
                                                      }).toList(),
                                                      onChanged: (value) {
                                                        setState(() {
                                                          _salutation = value!;
                                                        });
                                                      },
                                                    ),
                                                  )),
                                              Container()
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),

                    
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: you have to understand the concept of `Row` , `Column`, `Wrap` , and `Expanded` first.
then you will find how to achive that

Comment: what do you mean by 'close like in the design'?

Answer (score 0):

Use [dropdown_button2](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_button2) package,

```
final List<String> _items = [
    'item 1',
    'item 2',
    'item 3',
    'item 4',
  ];
String _selectedValue; // use list of string for your dropdown children
// put these above of build function
.
.
Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              MyDropdown(
                selectedValue: _selectedValue,
                dropdownItems: _items,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(width: 10),
        Expanded(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              MyDropdown(
                selectedValue: _selectedValue,
                dropdownItems: _items,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(width: 10),
        Expanded(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: const [
              Text('*To be filled ........'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

and here is your Dropdown widget, i extract it to make clean code

```
class MyDropdown extends StatefulWidget {
  List<String> dropdownItems;
  String selectedValue;
  MyDropdown({this.dropdownItems, this.selectedValue});

  @override
  State<MyDropdown> createState() => _MyDropdownState();
}

class _MyDropdownState extends State<MyDropdown> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButtonFormField2(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        isDense: true,
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
        ),
      ),
      isExpanded: true,
      hint: const Text(
        'Select Your Gender',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
      ),
      icon: const Icon(
        Icons.arrow_drop_down,
        color: Colors.black45,
      ),
      iconSize: 30,
      buttonHeight: 60,
      buttonPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 10),
      items: widget.dropdownItems
          .map((item) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: item,
                child: Text(
                  item,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14,
                  ),
                ),
              ))
          .toList(),
      validator: (value) {
        // validate here
      },
      onChanged: (value) {
        //Do something when changing the item if you want.
      },
      onSaved: (value) {
        widget.selectedValue = value.toString();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

play with values and add `TextField` in child of column to get result